Error message is displayed on running npm start in the vs code terminal
Any npm command I enter in the VS Code Terminal while programming in React, an error message is displayed.
npm : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current
system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

npm audit

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess




I don't know what it is. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?
I have already done the troubleshooting process and have not got any success.

Are these npm commands running in other terminals except vscode’s terminal?

Yes, it does work in the command prompt.
